# How to disable / exclude specific steps from appearing in reports - Jmeter non GUI operation

Tags: groovy, jmeter, report

I have a question about Jmeter reports,
I have a thread that includes jdbc/Jssr223/HTTP samplers.
one of the steps is loop that iterate 2000 times, and inside it exists HTTP + Jssr223 sampler.
I run the test in non UI mode via command line, and than I see the results in csv.
The problem is that I do not need all the responses from that loop, however I want to see all the responses from other steps.
Is their a way to disable step from appearing in reports? or disable entire loop results from appearing in reports.
The problem will be when I run multi thread and than the CSV is unreadable. Is exists a way not to write specific step to reports regards.
provided my properties + Pic of the loop in test

[image]

```
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Results file configuration
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------

# This section helps determine how result data will be saved.
# The commented out values are the defaults.

# legitimate values: xml, csv, db.  Only xml and csv are currently supported.
#jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=csv


# true when field should be saved; false otherwise

# assertion_results_failure_message only affects CSV output
#jmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results_failure_message=true
#
# legitimate values: none, first, all
#jmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results=all
#
#jmeter.save.saveservice.data_type=true
#jmeter.save.saveservice.label=true
#jmeter.save.saveservice.response_code=true
# response_data is not currently supported for CSV output
#jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=false
# Save ResponseData for failed samples
#jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data.on_error=false
#jmeter.save.saveservice.response_message=true
#jmeter.save.saveservice.successful=true
#jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_name=true
#jmeter.save.saveservice.time=true
#jmeter.save.saveservice.subresults=true
#jmeter.save.saveservice.assertions=true
#jmeter.save.saveservice.latency=false
# Only available with HttpClient4
#jmeter.save.saveservice.connect_time=false
#jmeter.save.saveservice.samplerData=true
#jmeter.save.saveservice.responseHeaders=true
#jmeter.save.saveservice.requestHeaders=true
#jmeter.save.saveservice.encoding=false
#jmeter.save.saveservice.bytes=false
# Only available with HttpClient4
#jmeter.save.saveservice.sent_bytes=false
#jmeter.save.saveservice.url=false
#jmeter.save.saveservice.filename=false
#jmeter.save.saveservice.hostname=false
#jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_counts=false
#jmeter.save.saveservice.sample_count=false
#jmeter.save.saveservice.idle_time=false

# Timestamp format - this only affects CSV output files
# legitimate values: none, ms, or a format suitable for SimpleDateFormat
#jmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format=ms
#jmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format=yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS

# For use with Comma-separated value (CSV) files or other formats
# where the fields' values are separated by specified delimiters.
# Default:
#jmeter.save.saveservice.default_delimiter=,
# For TAB, since JMeter 2.3 one can use:
#jmeter.save.saveservice.default_delimiter=\t

# Only applies to CSV format files:
# Print field names as first line in CSV
#jmeter.save.saveservice.print_field_names=true

# Optional list of JMeter variable names whose values are to be saved in the result data files.
# Use commas to separate the names. For example:
#sample_variables=SESSION_ID,REFERENCE
# N.B. The current implementation saves the values in XML as attributes,
# so the names must be valid XML names.
# Versions of JMeter after 2.3.2 send the variable to all servers
# to ensure that the correct data is available at the client.

# Optional xml processing instruction for line 2 of the file:
# Example:
#jmeter.save.saveservice.xml_pi=<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="../extras/jmeter-results-detail-report.xsl"?>
# Default value:
#jmeter.save.saveservice.xml_pi=

# Prefix used to identify filenames that are relative to the current base
#jmeter.save.saveservice.base_prefix=~/

# AutoFlush on each line written in XML or CSV output
# Setting this to true will result in less test results data loss in case of Crash
# but with impact on performances, particularly for intensive tests (low or no pauses)
# Since JMeter 2.10, this is false by default
#jmeter.save.saveservice.autoflush=false
```

Answer (score 0):

If your question is about Web report generated by Core JMeter (not ant), then set this property by only setting transactions you want to be in report:

> jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.series_filter=^(Search|Order)(-success|-failure)?$

Ensure you apply naming convention :

[image: Apply naming policy]

To end up with this for example:

[image: Naming policy applied]

Comment: this is about CSV, I do not want all the data just to pick the samplers

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude whatever results you don't need using [Filter Results Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FilterResultsTool/) like:

```
FilterResults.bat --output-file new.jtl --input-file old.jtl --exclude-label-regex true --exclude-labels "regular-expression-to-filter-unwanted-labels"
```

It will generate a new report with excluded samplers which you can specify via `excluded-labels` [Perl5-style regular expression](https://www.pcre.org/)

You can install Filter Results Tool using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

[image: JMeter Plugins Manager Filter Results]